# Dataflow concurrency error with ValueState

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

The Beam 2.1 pipeline uses ValueState in a stateful DoFn. It runs fine with a single worker but when scaling is enabled will fail with "Unable to read value from state" and the root exception below. Any ideas what could cause this?

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.KeyTokenInvalidException: Unable to fetch data due to token mismatch for key ��
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:500)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:459)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:76)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:62)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WindmillStateReader$WrappedFuture.get(WindmillStateReader.java:309)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WindmillStateInternals$WindmillValue.read(WindmillStateInternals.java:384)
... 16 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.KeyTokenInvalidException: Unable to fetch data due to token mismatch for key ��
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WindmillStateReader.consumeResponse(WindmillStateReader.java:469)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WindmillStateReader.startBatchAndBlock(WindmillStateReader.java:411)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WindmillStateReader$WrappedFuture.get(WindmillStateReader.java:306)
... 17 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that exception should just be rethrown. It is thrown by the state mechanism to indicate that additional work on that key should not be performed, and will be automatically retried by the Dataflow runner.

These typically indicate that either that particular work should be performed on a different worker (thus proceeding wouldn't be helpful).

It may be possible that misusing state -- storing the state object from one key and attempting to use it on a different key -- could also lead to these errors. If that is the case, you may be able to see more diagnostic messages in either the worker or shuffler logs in Stackdriver logging.

If neither retrying nor looking at logging and how you use the state objects help, please provide a job ID demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks, can scaling and migration to another worker manifest in other exceptions also? We observe seemingly unrelated errors with AvroCoder (java.lang.InstantiationException) that only occur after scaling kicks in. Should we expect an exception to occur at most once for a given element and key and subsequently processing succeed on the new worker? In the specific test we observe (after scaling) hundreds of exceptions occur over several minutes with throughput of ~1000 events/s.

Comment: InstantiationException is somewhat surprising, and may be an unrelated issue. Could you start a separate question thread with a stack trace and job ID, if possible?

Comment: It could be related to reads not really involving deserialization until scaling happens. Will check the decoding and open a new question if needed.